# Use Service Fabric Reverse Proxy with Azure Application Gateway

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-application-gateway

Is it possible to use Azure Application Gateway to route incoming traffic to a URL/Port and append a path? I want to do this so can use Service Fabric reverse proxy lookup.

i.e. I have a listener on ms-company.domain.com and I want it to redirect to http://servicefabric.domain.com:19081/**Company/Microservice/api/healthcheck**

That way even if I change the port that the micro-service lives in the Reverse Proxy lookup will work.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with the recent URL path override feature. Please refer to sample template at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/201-application-gateway-path-override/